# Deploy Laravel application only using FTP

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, laravel-5

I have finished a Laravel application and uploaded it using FTP but can't get it to work even after following multiple tutorials.

I can access the frontpage but when i go deeper like /login it gives an 500 internal server error. I can access /index.php/login but without css and bootstrap.

I have..

- Laravel public folder in public_html.
- The rest in an folder called app on the same level as public_html.
- Changed the bootstrap paths in index.php.
- Edited the .env file.
- Permission 755 for app/storage folder

Would appreciate if someone know what i'm doing wrong or a fix!

Comment: It's more likely the database isn't configured / migrations haven't ran or something. Best thing to do is look at the apache error log, if you get a 500, that's the first place you should look.

Comment: I exported the DB used in localhost and imported it into my production DB. I deleted everything in the laravel.log file after i was finished in localhost and it still empty.

Comment: Check the apache log - it will tell you the exact error.

Comment: And this is share host or your vps?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache webserver you should enable mod_rewrite module .
in the .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```